# CakePHP 3.4 how to insert on a belongs to and has many relationship

Tags: cakephp, save, associations, has-and-belongs-to-many, cakephp-3.x

On cakePHP 3.4, i have 3 tables with a belongs to and has many relationship: Ingredients, Products and IngredientsProducts:

```
class IngredientsTable extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        // Use through option because it looks like you 
        // have additional data on your IngredientsProducts table
        $this->belongsToMany('Products', [
            'through' => 'IngredientsProducts',
        ]);
    }
}

class ProductsTable extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        $this->belongsToMany('Ingredients', [
            'through' => 'IngredientsProducts',
        ]);
    }
 }

class IngredientsProductsTable extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        $this->belongsTo('Ingredients');
        $this->belongsTo('Products');
    }
}
```

What I want to accomplish is that when I insert a new product, I would like to insert also the ingredient_id(s) and field qty of each ingredient that is related to that product, on the **IngredientsProducts** joiner table.

I've been reading the cookbook, and saw that when saving aditional data on the joiner table (in my case the field qty as stated below), you have to use the _joinData property, so my add view looks like this:

```
    <?php 

    $this->Form->create($product);
    // fields of the Products table
    echo $this->Form->control('name',array('class' => 'form-control'));
    echo $this->Form->control('retail_price');
    echo $this->Form->control('best_before');
    echo $this->Form->control('comments');

    // ingredient_id and qty fields of the ingredients_products table
    echo $this->Form->control('ingredients.0._joinData.ingredient_id',['options' => $ingredients);

    echo $this->Form->control('ingredients.0._joinData.qty');

    //and repetition of these last two as ingredients.1._joinData to ingredients.N._joinData

$this->Form->button(__('Save'));
    $this->Form->end();

    ?>
```

and on the controller the add method looks like this:

```
$product = $this->Products->newEntity();
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {

            $product = $this->Products->patchEntity($product, $this->request->getData(),[
                'associated' => ['Ingredients._joinData']
            ]);


            if ($this->Products->save($product)) {
                $this->Flash->success(__('The product has been saved.'));

                return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
            }
            $this->Flash->error(__('The product could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
        $this->set(compact('product'));
        $this->set('_serialize', ['product']);
```

However when I submit it doesn't save anything. The debug displays the following being posted:

```
object(App\Model\Entity\Product) {

    'name' => 'salada',
    'retail_price' => (float) 23,
    'best_before' => (int) 234,
    'comments' => 'wer',
    'directions' => 'werwewerer',
    'ingredients' => [
        (int) 0 => object(App\Model\Entity\Ingredient) {

            '_joinData' => object(Cake\ORM\Entity) {

                'ingredient_id' => (int) 4,
                'qty' => (float) 100,
                '[new]' => true,
                '[accessible]' => [
                    '*' => true
                ],
                '[dirty]' => [
                    'ingredient_id' => true,
                    'qty' => true
                ],
                '[original]' => [],
                '[virtual]' => [],
                '[errors]' => [],
                '[invalid]' => [],
                '[repository]' => 'IngredientsProducts'

            },
            '[new]' => true,
            '[accessible]' => [
                '*' => true,
                'id' => false
            ],
            '[dirty]' => [
                '_joinData' => true
            ],
            '[original]' => [
                '_joinData' => [
                    'ingredient_id' => '4',
                    'qty' => '100'
                ]
            ],
            '[virtual]' => [],
            '[errors]' => [
                'name' => [
                    '_required' => 'This field is required'
                ]
            ],
            '[invalid]' => [],
            '[repository]' => 'Ingredients'

        },
        (int) 1 => object(App\Model\Entity\Ingredient) {

            '_joinData' => object(Cake\ORM\Entity) {

                'ingredient_id' => (int) 5,
                'qty' => (float) 200,
                '[new]' => true,
                '[accessible]' => [
                    '*' => true
                ],
                '[dirty]' => [
                    'ingredient_id' => true,
                    'qty' => true
                ],
                '[original]' => [],
                '[virtual]' => [],
                '[errors]' => [],
                '[invalid]' => [],
                '[repository]' => 'IngredientsProducts'

            },
            '[new]' => true,
            '[accessible]' => [
                '*' => true,
                'id' => false
            ],
            '[dirty]' => [
                '_joinData' => true
            ],
            '[original]' => [
                '_joinData' => [
                    'ingredient_id' => '5',
                    'qty' => '200'
                ]
            ],
            '[virtual]' => [],
            '[errors]' => [
                'name' => [
                    '_required' => 'This field is required'
                ]
            ],
            '[invalid]' => [],
            '[repository]' => 'Ingredients'

        }
    ],
    '[new]' => true,
    '[accessible]' => [
        '*' => true,
        'id' => false
    ],
    '[dirty]' => [
        'name' => true,
        'retail_price' => true,
        'best_before' => true,
        'comments' => true,
        'directions' => true,
        'ingredients' => true
    ],
    '[original]' => [],
    '[virtual]' => [],
    '[errors]' => [],
    '[invalid]' => [],
    '[repository]' => 'Products'

}
```

Does anybody happen to know how to make this work?

just in case here are the table structures on mySQL:

```
TABLE `Ingredients` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `category_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `measure_id` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


Table products
TABLE `Products` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `retail_price` float NOT NULL,
  `best_before` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `comments` text NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;



TABLE `ingredients_products` (
  `ingredient_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `qty` double NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Any help or directions would be kindly appreciated!
Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### When saving fails, check the `errors` info

Whenever saving an entity doesn't work, check the `errors` info:

```
'[errors]' => [
    'name' => [
        '_required' => 'This field is required'
    ]
],
```

Your validation rules define the `Ingredients.name` field as required, but it's not present in your form, hence saving fails.

### Supply the primary key on the target association

Take a closer look at the examples in the docs for saving join data, the data structure looks a little different to yours.

From your usage of `ingredient_id` I suspect that you want to link the product to existing ingredients, placing `ingredient_id` in the `_joinData` however is not how this works. Editing/linking existing records requires the primary key of the record to be present in either the special `_ids` key, or on the primary key field of the target association (`Ingredients`).

So in your case where you want to store additional join data, you have to use the `id` property for the ingredient, that way the marshaller knows that it needs to load an existing record:

```
echo $this->Form->control('ingredients.0.id', [
    // defining the type is required, as the input type
    // guessing only recognizes `_ids` fields, or fields
    // with `_id` appended as possible select types
    'type' => 'select'
    'options' => $ingredients
]);
echo $this->Form->control('ingredients.0._joinData.qty');
```

### See also

- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Saving Data > Converting BelongsToMany Data](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#converting-belongstomany-data)**
- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Saving Data > Saving BelongsToMany Associations](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#saving-belongstomany-associations)**
- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Saving Data > Saving Additional Data to the Join Table](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#saving-additional-data-to-the-join-table)**

Comment: I really appreciate your help and all the information. It's working now, thank you very much!